# To map - word usage in software context

Tags: terminology

I always get confused about how to use the verb "to map" in the context of associating objects with each other, particularly if the mapping is directional.

Is there a distinction between

> mapping users to IDs

and

> mapping IDs to users

In the given example, which would be the better way to put it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A *map from `X` to `Y`* would be something (function, table, data-structure) which, given an `X` (*from an `X`*), would allow you to retrieve the (often, but not necessarily, unique) corresponding `Y` (*to a `Y`*).

Something that maps IDs to users would allow you to retrieve a user given his/here ID. A map from users to IDs would be the opposite. A bi-directional mapping would allow you to do the search both ways.